# Python Parse xml file using xmltodict and add it to list

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xmltodict

I want to load and parse a xml file using xmltoDic and add it to a python list

my python file

```
import xmltodict
with open('input.xml') as fd:
my_dict= xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
entries = my_dict['Drivetrain']['Element']
elements=[]
for k in entries:
    print(type(k))
        #elements.append(k['@name'])
#print(elements)
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Drivetrain> 
<Element  name="PowerUnit">
  <Element  name="Transmission">
        <Element  name="TX1">
        </Element>
        <Element  name="TX2">
        </Element> 

  </Element>

  <Element  name="Engine">
        <Element  name="V4">
        </Element>
        <Element  name="V6">
        </Element>

    </Element>
  </Element>
  </Drivetrain>
```

display python list output

Comment: I ended using beautifulsoup and this can be done using few lines of code .I will post the code shortly